# Setting first field in a combo box to null

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, selectedindex

I have a databound ComboBox on my form. Is there any way that I can make the first field blank.

I can do this with a DropDownList in the HTML part of .Net but is there a way to do it for a ComboBox?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code I used to overcome the problem...

ComboBox1.SelectedValue = -1

Comment: worked like magic! This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
ComboBox1.SelectedValue = -1
```

didn't work for me but this did:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
```

I would have though -1 would have been an invalid index value, but obviously not.

Kristian

Answer (score 3):

You can insert a blank entry into data source.

```
Public Class Data
 Public Property No() As Integer
 Public Property Name() As String
End Class
```

and List(of Data),

```
Dim mlist As New List(Of Data)() From
    {
        New Data() With {.Name = "", .No = 0},
        New Data() With {.Name = "One", .No = 1},
        New Data() With {.Name = "Two", .No = 2}
    }

ComboBox1.DataSource = mlist
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "No"
```

Comment: what I did was ComboBox1.SelectedValue = -1

Comment: @AVD actually your answer is what answers his question, thing is he had framed his question wrong